# vanish cache not starting up due to file storage parameter

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have varnish 4.0 installed on my centos 7 box my params file looks like:

```
RELOAD_VCL=1
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin
VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=5G
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
VARNISH_TTL=120
VARNISH_USER=varnish
VARNISH_GROUP=varnish
```

When I start up my varnish I get the following error:

```
Unit varnish.service has begun starting up.
varnishd[14888]: Error: (-sfile) "${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE}" does not exist and could not be created
systemd[1]: varnish.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
```

The owner of the files is varnish, I have run out of ideas how can I get this working.

Comment: What are some of the ideas you've already tried?

Comment: @awsmketchup so far i have tried getting varnish 4.0 and centos 7 to work with file as a storage back end, so i changed the setup to varnish 5.1 and ubuntu 16 and this has yielded results. I suspect my scenario above works with centos 5 or 6, haven't tested it though